# When discarding the card in the Love Letter, is it mandatory to show the card you had?

Tags: love-letter

I need a claryfication of the rules:

- Let's say another player uses Baron and compares his card with mine, mine being the lower valued one. I know that I'm out of this round at that point, but what happens to my card? Is it discarded face up (everyone learns what I had) and or face down (only the comparison-winning player gets that information)?
- Let's say someone uses the Prince on me. I have to discard a card and draw another one. Do I discard my card face up or face down, keeping the information what I had to myself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Tempest version of the rules is just a little bit vague - it *does* say that to play a card you discard it face up, it *does* say that your discarded cards go in front of you, it *does* say that when you're knocked out you place your card face up in front of you, it *doesn't* explicitly say that a card you discard to the Prince should be face up (although I'd say that they weight of all the other rules says yes it should).

The [Kanai](http://www.alderac.com/loveletter/files/2013/08/LL_Kanai_Rulesheet.pdf) version definitely spells it out:

- All discarded cards should remain in front of the player who played them, visible, so that it is clear in what order they were discarded.
- If a player is out of the round he or she must reveal the card in his or her hand (if any) and place it in front of him or her.

Comment: So basically, if I hold the Princess and someone plays Prince on me, forcing me to discard my card, I'm out of the round and everyone can see that I had a Princess. Correct?

Comment: From what I understand, Kanai version actually doesn't say that you have to put discarded card (from the Prince) face up. It only says it must be in front of you, visible and in order (i.e. Guard, face-down-card, Priest). Which it is, even if it's face down.

Comment: The quote I just put there (the bullet points are directly copied from the rules) says *all* discarded cards go in front of you face up, which would include those from the Prince. And yes, if the Prince causes you to discard the Princess, you're out of the round.

Comment: Either we don't understand each other or I don't see the words "face up" in the bullet points quote.

Comment: I'm reading that the cards should be "visible" means that the actual value of the cards should be visible. Especially since there is never a mention of any cards, except the one set aside at the beginning of the round, ever being face down.

Comment: I'd also add that if you look on BoardGameGeek's Love Letter page in the Rules forum there are many, many threads asking about the Prince/Princess effect, and everyone (including people involved in playtesting and/or localising the game) agrees that you lose the round.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is mandatory to show your card in both cases. The [Nordic](http://bgg.geekdo.com/boardgameversion/252591/nordic-edition-2014) version has very clear rules for these:

### Baron

> Player with the smaller number in the card drops out from the round

and (from "Dropping out of the game")

> If a player drops out of the game, he puts his card on front of him **face up**..

### Prince

> The player of your choise puts his card into his discard pile..

and (from "How to play")

> **Cards in the** [players own] **discard pile are kept so that even all the cards played earlier can be seen**.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely. If you are knocked out by a Baron or any other card, you must discard your card face up so anyone can see. Also, at any given time,  **any player can look through any other player's discarded cards stack.** Also, when you discard a card  *for any reason*, it goes face up in your stack.This goes for playing cards, etc.

Answer (score 1):

yes its very clear

out of the round
If a player is knocked out of the 
round, that player discards the card 
in his or her hand face up (do not 
apply the card’s effect) and takes 
no more turns until next round.

http://www.alderac.com/tempest/files/2012/09/Love_Letter_Rules_Final.pdf

Comment: The rulebook (as linked) says under Prince Arnaud: "That player discards his or her hand (do not apply its effect) and draws a new card."  The crux of the initial question is whether that discard is *face up* or *face down*, which is *not* specified in the rules.

Comment: @hexparrot That's right, thanks. Also, zergs78 - welcome to the B&CG! :)